# App crashes when clicking on loading icon on user's "All accounts"

Tags: bug, android-app

App version: 1.0.27

If a user has an account on a few different Stack Exchange sites (like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/318330/john-wayland-bales) guy)

- Click the "All *N* sites" button (actually that text could be worded a bit differently?)
- Click into one of the sites listed
- Go back a screen and click on the loading icon
- Voilà the app crashes!

I have included the logcat of the crash below.

Logcat:

```
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.user.AllNetworkUsersFragment$1.onItemClick(AllNetworkUsersFragment.java:63)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
03-25 22:25:21.492 E/AndroidRuntime(22209):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

<sup>Note: the user is randomly chosen with having less than 8 sites to show the issue</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**Good news!** Since 1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, tapping the loading icon won't crash the app, but...

**Bad news...** The loading indicator won't go away, even if you don't interact with it.

[image: that loading indicator...]